# How to remove specific data loss warnings using DACPAC DeploymentPlanModifier?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools, dacpac

I have a [DeploymentPlanModifier](https://www.google.com/search?q=DeploymentPlanModifier&oq=DeploymentPlanModifier&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.376j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) implementation that, for simplicity, remove any [AlterElementStep](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dac.deployment.alterelementstep(v=sql.120).aspx) from the deployment plan that have [AlterTableDropTableElementStatement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.transactsql.scriptdom.altertabledroptableelementstatement.aspx) script statements in it.

This makes sure that no `ALTER TABLE ... DROP COLUMN ...` is generated in the deployment script. The deployment script and the deployment report, however, still gets generated with data loss checks (on the former) and warnings (on the latter) due to removed columns.

For the deployment script checks, I found that I could parse the script generated by [DeploymentScriptSteps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dac.deployment.deploymentscriptstep(v=sql.120).aspx) and remove those steps associated to the data loss check for the columns I did not drop. However I'm still looking for a similar alternative for the deployment report.

I do not want to disable data loss warnings/checks altogether. I just want to manipulate the checks/warnings associated to the columns I am touching as part of my plan modifications.

Is there a better way to remove data loss checks and warnings from both artifacts without manually parsing the generated output?

Answer (score 0):

I've got a deployment contributor that does a similar thing (don't drop columns) and someone submitted a pull request where they did the same thing and th only way they could do it was to parse the generated output

This is how he did it:

https://agilesqlclub.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#SqlPackageFilter/Filter/DataLossCheckStep.cs

Ed

Comment: Thank you. That's a nice project. It seems indeed a similar approach to the one I took. I was hoping however there was a less "hands-on" approach, that didn't require altering the final artifact (especially for the deployment report).